# How to learn location of the web user?

Tags: geolocation, gps, location

We have started developing an application for location aware emergency service. The users can connect through computer,smart phone or even through WAP.

The problem we are facing is, we don't know how to get the location of the user who is asking for service. If it is GPS enabled smart phone, it can be located though the app. I have seen google map locating the cell phone using BTS tower's location in GPS-less smart phones (Like Nokia E-series). But I couldn't find any API in Nokia site which I can use to get that location or BTS tower based locating service.

And the main problem remains for the computer. It is enough if I can locate the city for computers. I have seen in several sites (like ip2location.com) locating the IP address up to the city level (sometimes more). Isn't there any other way to locate IP address for free of charge?

If I summarize my questions-

1. How to get BTS tower based location service for cell phones?
2. How to locate user's IP address upto at least city level ?
3. How to convert the latitude-longitude into address (at least up to city level)? free of charge?
4. How to convert the address into latitude-longitude? free of charge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone already beat you to this app.  It's called 911. :)

Comment: Interestingly, 911 is becoming problematic.  #1, it's hard to tell where mobile phone calls come from and #2, it's hard to tell where VoIP calls are coming from.

Comment: well, for my application, I don't want to track calls. I want to track the users locations through the app (in most cases) when they are requesting service. Also, the location of the computer and gps-less phones is a big headache.

Comment: not that many of the ad's that appear on your screen are location based (ever notice that 'some sites' have pop-ups that purport to be 'people' where you are located wanting to 'chat'?)

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 is geocoding (and #3 is called ...... reverse geocoding)

Look at the source for android, it seems to triangulate based on cell-tower (when no GPS or WiFi are available)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, for android or iphone, this is not a problem since these devices already are GPS enabled. Problem is with gps-less smart phones like Nokia S60 series. Or the java enabled phones. And the major problem is how to locate the computer users.

Comment: So what makes my answer incorrect?  The source for android will have the triangulation algorithm you're looking for you just need to modify it to work on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few common providers of cell-tower triangulation (or increasingly common, WiFi network triangulation): Skyhook Wireless, Google and Apple.

You could try to make deals with these companies, or install their custom software on everyone's devices, but that sounds like a lot of work. I think more successful will be to take advantage of some framework abstraction that will work on a lot of devices without your software having to deal with each detail.

The W3C Geolocation API provides an implementation-agnostic access to a device's current location for modern browsers (on desktop, laptop and mobile) that support it, if your users are using the Web. As you've seen, there are also native platform-specific frameworks (CoreLocation on iPhone and Mac OS X, the Windows 7 Location Platform, Android's LocationManager, etc.).

As mentioned already, geocoding and reverse-geocoding services can help you with the step for translating between lat-lon coordinates and civic addresses, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about super-fine accuracy, and you don't want to annoy your user with an alert requesting their permission to access their location, then you can make use of something like [FreeGeoIP](http://freegeoip.net).  I've written a small jQuery plugin that makes use of this.  See the [Locaternator](https://github.com/davesag/locaternator). Supports `jsonp` requests too so you can use it from any website, including static html only webs.