# How can I get the location of a user?

Tags: php, javascript, html, geolocation, location

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the city and state of where a user is located. How can I do this? Should I use JavaScript, PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn location of the web user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026786/how-to-learn-location-of-the-web-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use [ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) for PHP, where you get the user information based on the IP. I'm located in Sweden, and I find it very accurate even here. Though there is always a problem when the ISPs are hiding their customers location, but it has nothing to do with the API accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

Depends, on how cross platform you wish to be. In HTML5, there is the [Geolocation api](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/). I would recommend using that, if you don't need to support all IE browsers, and are looking for an HTML5 solution.

Edited to add a much more [developer friendly link](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html).

Comment: +1 for geolocation, but you can of course fall back to something like maxmind's [geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) if the function isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [javascript geolocation API](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm) to locate the user, then make an AJAX call to a PHP or other server-side script to store the location information.

Comment: Interesting, I've also noticed in the first paragraph of that article the author also includes a link to an article using the user's IP to roughly locate them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably PHP in case you want to store it or something. I found this on some forum after a google search and modified it. I'm not sure how accurate it is, but it find my location to within a one hour drive.

```
<?

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (!empty($IP)) {
        $location=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$ip);

        list($country, $city) = explode("\n", $location);
        list($country, $code) = explode(' (', $country);
        list($city, $state) = explode(', ', $city);
        $code = substr($code, 0, 2);
        $country = ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace("Country: ", "", $country)));
        $city = ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace("City: ", "", $city)));
    }

echo 'Country: '.$country.'<br />';
echo 'City: '.$city.'<br />';
echo 'State: '.$state.'<br />';
echo 'Country Code: '.$code.'<br />';

?>
```

Not sure if it's up to date.

Comment: This will find an approximation for the location of the reported IP address, which may not be exactly the same as the location of the human using the computer (so somebody going through a corp. proxy from a remote location could be very far from the IP address location).

Answer (score 0):

```
$country=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=');
echo $country;

// Reformat the data returned (Keep only country and country abbr.)
$only_country=explode (" ", $country);

echo "Country : ".$only_country[1]." ".substr($only_country[2],0,4);
```